# JavaFX Object moving on pah without pause on start/finish

Tags: java, javafx

I try to make a object ( here i use a circle) move on a circle path, but i notice that the object make an pause on the starting point, how can i have a fluid movement without pause on the starting point ? There is another element that PathTransition, i think that is the cause ?

```
package main.java;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class PathCircle extends Application {

private PathTransition pathTransition;

public static void main(String args[]){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Circle Path");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800, Color.GREEN);

    SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
    svg.setContent("M-200,0a200,200 0 1,0 400,0a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0");
    svg.setLayoutX(350);
    svg.setLayoutY(200);
    svg.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    svg.setFill(Color.NAVY);
    svg.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    //Drawing a object
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.setCenterX(300.0f);
    circle.setCenterY(235.0f);
    circle.setRadius(10.0f);
    circle.setFill(Color.RED);

    //Creating a path transition 1
    pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setNode(circle);
    pathTransition.setPath(svg);
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
    pathTransition.play();

    root.getChildren().add(svg);
    root.getChildren().add(circle);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

  }
}
```

Thanks you

Comment: Check out [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) code with the Earth and Sun.

Comment: Thanks you James_D, you r right, i must use the pathTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)